# Getting verification to use Google APIs via identity.lanchWebAuthFlow() for a Firefox addon

Tags: firefox, google-api, firefox-addon, google-oauth, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm currently having a lot of trouble with the google API support team and was wondering if anyone had figured out their process.  I'm developing an extension that uses `identity.launchWebAuthFlow()` to authenticate with google for google drive access.  Since July 2017, google has started requiring "Verification" for oauth. As I don't own my extension's domain `{random}.extensions.allizom.org`, I have no idea how to pass their verification requirements.

You can read about that process here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification

They've rejected me once saying my client id is `deleted or invalid or does not need verification` - I verified that the client exists, is still servicing requests, and still produces the unverified warning screen detailed in the link above.

When I reached out specifically to webstore support, the response said:

> Dear Brandon,
>
> Thank you for contacting Chrome Web Store Developer Support! I understand that you're having an issue regarding developing a web extension for both Chrome and Firefox using Google Drive API. As much as I'd love to assist you, unfortunately, our team cannot offer much support on this matter. My best advice is to ask the community on Stackoverflow, or create a bug report directly to the Chrome Browser/Extension experts using the Chromium Public Issue Tracker. The engineers are actively working on the reported problems on this list, so I'm sure that you'll be able to get the information that you're looking for.
>
> I appreciate your understanding and cooperation. Please let me know if there's anything else I can do for you, I'm happy to assist. :)
>
> Warm Regards,
> [Redacted]
> Chrome Web Store Developer Support

Again the major problem here is that I cannot prove ownership of the identity.getRedirectUri() for my extension as the requirements state.  I know other addons use google APIs, but I don't know if this verification process is a way to ban firefox developers from the google api ecosystem.

As a bit of question justification, I can find no documentation anywhere from July 18 2017 or later where developers have run into this, and I think this question will provide significant value to any Firefox addon developers who seek to use any of Google's APIs.